# Sum DataTable Columns

Tags: c#

Trying to do a sum of each column in a DataTable that i have set up. The First 2 columns in the datatable contain text and the rest of the columns contain numeric values that i would like to sum.

I get a error saying there is no row at position 17.

when i scroll down the DataTable viewer you can see there is no row at 17 and cant see why the foreach is hitting this row.
[image]

I have the following code

```
for (int i = 2; i < DT.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    foreach (DataRow DR in DT.Rows)
    {
        ColumnTotal = ColumnTotal + int.Parse(DR[i].ToString());
    }
    DT.Rows[DT.Rows.Count + 1][i] = ColumnTotal;
    ColumnTotal = 0;
}
```

Can anyone advise me on what i am doing wrong and how i can improve on it.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try `DT.AsEnumerable().Sum(x =>x.Field<int>( "ColumnName"));`.. Also it seems you can also use [DataTable.Compute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: maybe you should add data row for sum, because `DT.Rows[DT.Rows.Count + 1]` is out of bounds of `DT.Rows` array?

Comment: exclude the last row. use for(j=0; j< DT.RowCount;j++)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to assign in `17-th` row but it does not exist. So first create it and then populate it like below:

```
var row = DT.NewRow();
for (int i = 2; i < DT.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    ColumnTotal = 0;
    foreach (DataRow DR in DT.Rows)
    {
        ColumnTotal = ColumnTotal + int.Parse(DR[i].ToString());
    }
    row[i] = ColumnTotal;
}
DT.Rows.Add(row);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not set the value in row like this

```
DT.Rows[DT.Rows.Count + 1][i] = ColumnTotal;
```

Because it has no 17th row, You may need to add a new row.

Do something like,

```
DataRow newRow = DT.NewRow();

for (int i = 2; i < DT.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    foreach (DataRow DR in DT.Rows)
    {
        ColumnTotal = ColumnTotal + int.Parse(DR[i].ToString());
    }

    newRow[i] = ColumnTotal;

    ColumnTotal = 0;
}

DT.Rows.Add(newRow);
```

Answer (score 0):

simple my dear friend

```
Datatable Dt=new DataTable();
Dt.Columns.Add("Name");
Dt.Columns.Add("Amount");
Dt.Columns.Add("Id");
Dt.Rows.Add("Harsh","100", "1");
Dt.Rows.Add("Miller","200", "2");
```

now to calculate use this

```
object Sum = Dt.Compute(" SUM(Amount) ","");
double NetTotal = Double.Parse(Sum.ToString());
```